# Can I use a helper class by USE dynamic variable in php?

Tags: php

Can I do this using USE by variable name.

```
use scripts\helpers\$table_use_name;
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "helpers/$table_use_name";
$table = new $class_name;
```

Comment: yes and i get error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, but before that i get an error in netbeans.

Comment: I don't think you can use variables in `use` statement. Just use fully qualified names.

Comment: The `unexpected T_USE` suggests you are using it in an incorrect context to begin with. Post more of the surrounding code. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope

Comment: ^^ But as that paragraph states, `use` importing is a compile-time event, so you can't do it dynamically - the alternative is to prefix `$class_name` with the full namespace..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `use` on a dynamic expression, no. However, what you're wanting to do is fairly common. Do it like this:

```
// Assumes $table_use_name is the name of the class file on disk,
// and $class_name is the name of the PHP class
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "helpers/{$table_use_name}.php";

$full_class = "scripts\\helpers\\{$class_name}";
$table = new $full_class();
```

Of course, it is worth putting this in a function, so you don't have to repeat the same logic several times.

Also, you can drop the `require_once` by implementing an autoloader in your application bootstrap.